# QT: Build old project with old clang compiler on Mac with up-to-date QT version and Clang

Tags: macos, qt, compilation, version

Motivation:  As part of my daily work, I need from time to time, to solve issues on old version of my application.
Issue: I have a bug which I need to fix on old version. This version was built and compiled with QT 4.7.4 ( QT Creator 2.4.1).
I have QT 5.2 on my Mac machine (Os version: 10.9.3, Clang: 5.1 LLVM 3.4svn) so I installed QtSDK (4.7.4) as well.

No matter what I tried to do, I could find a way to install old version of Clang compiler and configure QTCreator to use it. 
I know I need CLang 4.1 LLVM 3.1svn but QTCreator 2.4.1 (for Qt 4.7.4) cannot find it or use it .

The bottom line: How can I have several versions of Clang compiler on my Mac and how can I set QTCreator to use specific compiler?
I would expect it to be simple just as I have Visual Studio 2005, 2010 and 2012 on my one Windows platform and each of which uses it's own relevant compiler.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to stick to the old version of Qt and clang compiler? Why can't you spend some time once and port the app to Qt5.x and a newer compiler?

Comment: We have different versions of the application.
Some are based on QT5.x and few on QT4.x.
We keep supporting the old versions and bug fixes are done on the relevant platform